# Leaflet marker's popup fade in and out

Tags: javascript, angular, leaflet

I've been working in a map web app with angular, there are several markers and I would like make the popups fade in and out by themselves (with a timer), but I have no idea how:

The code I use to make the markers with the popups is

```
  L.marker([50.627141, 3.203248], {icon: newico}).bindPopup('<h4>Swing dancing 17:30</h4><p>Place des fleurs</p>').addTo(myfrugalmap).openPopup();
```

Thank you

Comment: What does "by themselves" mean exactly? Should the popups fade in when added to the map and fade out when removed from it? Or should them have a fade in-out cycle?

Answer (score 2):

```
L.marker([LatLng], {
  icon: L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'YourIcon',
    className: 'blink'
  })
}).addTo(myfrugalmap);
L.DomUtil.addClass(marker._icon, "blink");
```

CSS:

```
#map {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

@keyframes fade { 
  from { opacity: 0.8; } 
}

.blink {
  animation: fade 1s infinite alternate;
}
```

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, he's asking on how to animate it, not how to remove it

Comment: Oh, sorry. He needs to add css then.

Comment: Updated Accordingly

Comment: @joseMolinaChe0 Please accept the answer if it has worked out for you!

Comment: Thank you, but what I want to fade in-out are the popups not the markers

Comment: @JoseMolinaChe0 Refer the following link  **https://css-tricks.com/transition-delay-delays/**